# Excel Cells converts August 2016 to date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question about excel. Tried to understand - why does excel thinks, that, when i input in cell "August 2015", it converts cell to date, while, when i enter - "January 2015" it shows it as text. 
Thanks.

Comment: I dont know much about Excel, but this ( http://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-using-dates-times-excel/ ) might help you.

Comment: No answer there, I know all those functions, etc., but why it converts August, no info. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Is the cell in which you enter "January 2015" pre-formatted as Text? If entered into cells formatted as General, for example, both of those are interpreted as dates for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible format difference in pasted cells because there is no reason to convert "August 2015" but not convert "January 2015". If you are sure that you have correctly spelled both month and formats of cells are same.

Excel converts some certain patterns i.e. if there is a `"-"` in a data or `":"` converts this to date or time automatically.

In order to avoid this automatic conversion:

- Right click on the cell
- Format Cells -> Numbers -> Text
- Paste your data or type it
- Click "Match Destination formatting"

Comment: absolutely, format the cells first and type/copy afterwards, otherwise you may get different results.

Comment: also adding a leading ' will automatically display as text

Comment: @InContext +1 you are absolutely right and also a space in before the first letter is also quite handy.